# Python/MVS - Standard library module invoked

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, standard-library

I'm trying to run the following code on Microsoft Visual Studio (Python 3.6, 64-bit) and receive the error message that "Standard library module invoked user code during import; breakpoints disabled for invoked code"

I really hope you can help me. I have no experience in MVS.
Thank you!!

Please find my code below:

```
Newton raphson method.
from __future__ import division
from unittest.test.test_result import __init__
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cplane_np import ArrayComplexPlane
from math import sqrt

####################################################################
class NewtonRaphson(ArrayComplexPlane):
"""define a class called NewtonRaphson which is a subclass from     
ArrayComplexPlane"""
def __init__(self):
    ArrayComplexPlane.__init__(self, -2, 2, 401, -2, 2, 401)
    self.z= ArrayComplexPlane(-2, 2, 401, -2, 2, 401).plane
    om=self.z
    om1= om.as_matrix()
    self.resu= self.meth2()
    ###Array of roots and iterations.

self.plo= self.plo_res()

def meth1(self,z0=3):


    x0=z0    #The initial value.
    n=0    # The initial value of iterations.
    dx=0.01
    dy=0.01
    eps=sqrt(dx**2+dy**2)

    while df(x0)!=0:    #the derivation of f(x) should be not equal to zero.

        n+=1
        #x1=self.apply(new_fun(x0))
        x1= new_fun(x0)
        if abs(x1-x0)< eps: #The condition to stop the iteration
            return (x1,n)
        else:
            x0=x1   #assign new value of x1 to x0

def meth2(self):
    ve= np.vectorize(self.meth1 )
    return ve(self.z)

def plo_res(self):
    res1=self.resu
    res_11= np.array(res1[0],dtype='float')
    plt.imshow(res_11)
    return plt.show()
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOq1I.png)

Comment: I get into same issue..

Answer (score 1):

For future reference: this is expected to be fixed in visual studio 2017 15.6

https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/3408

To fix this before it gets out follow the suggestions as posted in the above github thread:

> If you'd like to try it right now, you should be able to overwrite
>   your copy of debugger.py with the latest version at
>   https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/blob/master/Python/Product/PythonTools/ptvsd/debugger.py
>
> (search for debugger.py under your microsoft visual studio install
>   directory)
>
> It's possible that these warnings may have been the cause of the
>   "debugger operation in progress" or made it much worse.